# Stellar sent from Ledger Live (Nano s) without my authorization. Prior to this on six occasions small amounts were received

Tags: transactions, lumens, ledger-nano

I have been hacked as most of my Stellar Lumens were withdrawn from ledger Live (secured by Nano S) without my authority. Prior to the Stellar coins being withdrawn the Ledger Live Stellar account shows six tiny transactions received. This activity looks like phishing.  However can't see how Lumens could be withdrawn without Nano S being present. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to hear that you have been the victim of hacking.  My guess is that those tiny payments you received are spam, and that if you look at the memo field for them, you will see text that is promoting something, or a URL someone is trying to get you to click.

However, unless they get you to click a URL and sign a transaction that transfers funds out of your Ledger Nano account, those spam payments are harmless.  Annoying, but harmless.

It sounds like your issue is with the Ledger nano — it should be impossible for someone to authorize a payment without accessing that device to sign it — and so the best thing to do at this point is to contact Ledger support and see if they can help:
https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears you have been the victim of a scam.  There is no staking on Stellar.  If you look closely at the email address that contacted you, you will likely find that it is not from `@stellar.org`.  Likewise, the URL of the site you visited will likely resemble `https://www.stellar.org/`, but it will be _slightly_ different.  For more info, please see: https://www.stellar.org/blog/stellar-security-guide-protect-scammers